# How to use Google Translate Api key

Tags: r, api, google-translate, translate, sentiment-analysis

I registered in the Google Cloud platform and I create my API key.
However, when I use it in r it doesn't work. Could someone give me some suggestion? thank you very much. E.

Comment: Can you please show how you tried using it

Comment: I installed the packages translate end the other packages required.

Comment: set.key('YOUR-API-KEY')
translate('Hello, world!', 'en', 'de')

Answer (score 0):

though it is difficult to help you without knowing which package you are using, you may be experiencing problems related to rate limiting or two step authentication with your google account. Try disabling two step authentication or log in to your email to see if Google has blocked your account because they suspect it is being used for "suspicious activity"

Also- because it appears you are new to r- ensure that you have loaded the package before using the setapi function

Answer (score 0):

Make a Translation API request

We will make a Translation API Request using the v2 REST method.

> Create a JSON request file with the following text, and save it as a
>   translate-request.json plain text file:

```
{
  'q': 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.',
  'source': 'en',
  'target': 'es',
  'format': 'text'
}
```

This JSON snippet includes the text (query) to translate within the q field. We include the source language using the iso-169-1 code for English ("en") and the target language for Spanish ("es"). The format of the query is noted as "text" (for plain text).

> Authenticate to your service account, passing the location of your
>   service account key file:

```
$ gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=service-account-key-file
```

> Obtain an authorizaton token using your service account:

```
$ gcloud auth print-access-token
access_token
```

> Use curl to make a v2 request, passing it the access token you
>   printed, and the filename of the JSON request you set up in step 1:

```
$ curl -s -k -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    -H 'Authorization: Bearer access_token' \
    'https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2 \
    -d @translate-request.json
```

Note that to pass a filename to curl you use the -d option (for "data") and precede the filename with an @ sign. This file should be in the same directory in which you execute the curl command.

You should see a response similar to the following:

```
{
  "data": {
    "translations": [
      {
        "translatedText": "El zorro rápida saltó sobre el perro perezoso."
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Congratulations! You've sent your first request to the Cloud Translation API!